# Guice CreationException due to missing implementation for java.util.Optional

Tags: java, guice

I'm upgrading an application written for Java 7 to version 8. It uses Guice to inject config values into the constructor of an object. However, after the upping the Java version, I'm now getting this mysterious error when running unit tests:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.inject.CreationException: Guice creation errors:

1) No implementation for java.util.Optional<java.lang.Boolean> annotated with @Config(value=AsyncHttpClientConfigProvider.allowPoolingConnection) was bound.
  while locating java.util.Optional<java.lang.Boolean> annotated with @Config(value=AsyncHttpClientConfigProvider.allowPoolingConnection)
    for field at AsyncHttpClientConfigProvider.allowPoolingConnection(AsyncHttpClientConfigProvider.java:212)
  at Module.configure(Module.java:24)

...


13 errors
    at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:435)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:154)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:106)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:95)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:72)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
    at org.jukito.JukitoRunner.ensureInjector(JukitoRunner.java:105)
    at org.jukito.JukitoRunner.computeTestMethods(JukitoRunner.java:233)
    ... 19 more
```

What might I be missing that would cause this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trivially, you're missing a binding of `@Config(AsyncHttpClientConfigProvider.allowPoolingConnection) Optional<Boolean>`, which is different from `@Config(AsyncHttpClientConfigProvider.allowPoolingConnection) Boolean`. For a more specific answer, we'll need to see more of your previous working injection point and current failing injection point, but given that java.util.Optional didn't exist before Java 8, it's likely that you added that yourself and thus changed the Guice Key used to look up the binding.

Support for [Java 8's `Optional<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html), like the rest of Java 8 support, came out in [Guice 4.0 (Apr 2015)](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Guice40), and only when using the [Multibindings `OptionalBinder`](http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/4.0/javadoc/com/google/inject/multibindings/OptionalBinder.html). Without that, or in previous versions of Guice, your Injector will treat Optional like any other generic type when used as a Key.

Guice 3.0's "optional" bindings were restricted to method and field injections with `@Inject(optional=true)`, which still works, but nothing in Guice 4.0's upgrades automatically supports Optional types outside of the Multibindings case.